# pandas.read_excel () exits with OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer

Tags: python, excel, pandas

While reading an excel file with pandas inbuilt function read_excel(), an error occurs:

`OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer`

Reason is a value of "1.79769313486232E+308" in some cells of the excel file. This file is written by a measurement device and might indicate a "inf". This "inf"-values are written randomly and not in each file. By replacing the value manually in the excel-file, the file is correctly imported. But that wasn't the intention for writing this script ;-).

I tried these arguments:

```
data=pd.read_excel(path +'/'+file,
                   sheet_name='Sheet1',
                   skiprows=[1],
                   na_values='1.79769313486232E+308',
                   keep_default_na=True)
```

and

```
data=pd.read_excel(path +'/'+file,
                   sheet_name='Sheet1',
                   skiprows=[1],
                   na_values=1.79769313486232E+308,
                   keep_default_na=True)
```

but everytime with the same result.

Has anyone any idea how to handle this problem?

edit:

`Pandas version: 1.2.4`

`Engine: xlrd`

Exporting the sheet as csv:

instead of previously mentioned value a
`########################################################################################################################################################################################################`
is written into the file.

exporting the sheet as another xls:

`#NUM!` is written in the very same cell where before this number was written.

Comment: I can't reproduce this. Can you provide sample data in the spreadsheet?

Comment: Can you try to save the .xls as .csv and try pd.read_csv? Same issue?

Comment: I also can't repro this, what engine are you using?

Comment: Thanks for testing. I checked the suggestions and wrote the results under the topic "Edit:" directly into the question.