# How to deal with infinite values when uploading excel file via pd.read_excel()

Tags: python, pandas, excel, infinite-value

I am trying to upload a .xls file using `pd.read_excel()`. I have the needed additional package `xlrd`, the problem is that there are infinite values in the excel sheet that python cannot convert to an integer, which throws this error:

```
    481         "Engine should not be specified when passing "
    482         "an ExcelFile - ExcelFile already has the engine set"
    483     )
    485 try:
--> 486     data = io.parse(
    487         sheet_name=sheet_name,
    488         header=header,
    489         names=names,
    490         index_col=index_col,
    491         usecols=usecols,
    492         dtype=dtype,
    493         converters=converters,
    494         true_values=true_values,
    495         false_values=false_values,
    496         skiprows=skiprows,
    497         nrows=nrows,
...
--> 109     val = int(cell_contents)
    110     if val == cell_contents:
    111         cell_contents = val

OverflowError: cannot convert float infinity to integer
```

Infinite values in excel are represented as the number `1.79769313486232E+308`. I've tried to specify this value in the `na_values=` parameter of `pd.read_excel()` to no avail. Ex)

```
na_values=1.79769313486232E+308
```

Ive also tried the `converters` parameter and passed in this func

```
def convert(n):
    return np.inf
```

like so

```
converters={1.79769313486232E+308: convert(1.79769313486232E+308)}
```

How can I deal with this and successfully upload the .xls file?

Comment: Does your `read_excel` call use the `dtype` parameter? i.e. what's the full `read_excel` call?

Comment: @BigBen its just ```pd.read_excel('fname.xls')```

Comment: @BigBen yes, sorry for not clarifying

Comment: I can't repro this, and I believe the maximum number possible in Excel is  
[9.99999999999999E+307](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/office/excel-specifications-and-limits-1672b34d-7043-467e-8e27-269d656771c3). What version of pandas?

Comment: @BigBen `2.0.3`

Comment: I can't repro in 2.0.3. Please share a table with some sample values from your Excel file.

Comment: This post [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71128229/pandas-read-excel-exits-with-overflowerror-cannot-convert-float-infinity-to) has the same infinity value, however their problem is slightly different.

Comment: The comment about `1.79769313486232E+308` suggests this is a LibreOffice file. Is that the case?

Comment: @BigBen I'm not sure, its an output from a model at work that I don't have full access to. If that is how LibreOffice outputs infinite values, then it probably is the case.